# Maven dependency analysis falsely announces spring-boot-starter-data-jpa as unused

Tags: spring-boot, maven

On cleaning the dependencies of my multi module Maven project I encountered this issue.
In one of the submodules

```
mvn dependency:analyze
```

announces the following dependency as unused

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

But it is in fact used, which is easily verified on removing it; then the build fails due to missing packages com.zaxxer.hikari etc.

Also some dependencies declared in spring-boot-starter-data-jpa (e.g. org.hibernate:hibernate-core) are claimed as used. but not declared.

Spring boot is included in the parent pom like this

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
```

I tried to set scope to import for spring-boot-starter-data-jpa, but this changes nothing.

Why does dependency:analyze not recognize it as used, and what can I do to fix this?

Comment: Generally, the `dependency:analyze` goes through your code and looks for uses. This does not include uses through reflection, injection etc. So this is not always correct. You can declare a list of exceptions in the dependency plugin declaration.

Comment: But these are directly used, not via reflection. They are not runtime dependencies, but needed for compilation.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that is a good idea to enforce dependencies using `maven-dependency-plugin` in `spring-boot` projects, the problem is `dependency:analyze` checks produced bytecode and verifies that the only compile-time dependencies are defined in `pom`. However, in case of `spring-boot` projects their dependencies do contain a lot of infrastructure stuff which is required to run application but not required to compile code (i.e. runtime dependencies), so, the general idea of managing `maven-dependency-plugin` in case of `spring-boot` projects would be following:

- mark all non-compile-time dependencies as `runtime`, i.e. `<scope>runtime</scope>`
- tel `maven-dependency-plugin` to ignore runtime dependencies, i.e. `<ignoreNonCompile>true</ignoreNonCompile>` (also, `<ignoreAllNonTestScoped>true</ignoreAllNonTestScoped>` might be helpful)

On the other hand, doing the above does not make much sense cause we are just moving the mess to another place, and stronger idea would be to split project into submodules and properly manage dependencies in those submodules.

The bottom line is: `dependency:analyze` is good for libraries but it harms applications.

Comment: If the dependencies in question would only be necessary at runtime, the removal would not break the build. And spring-boot-starter dependencies contain only further dependencies afaik... And the submodule I analyze is a library. The applications are in different submodules, which I will not analyze so far.

Comment: Let's assume you start getting compile errors after marking `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` dependency as runtime, that means now you need to explicitly define some of it's trasitive dependencies (`org.hibernate`, `jakarta.persistence`, etc) as compile-time - that is a main purpose of `dependency:analyze`: get rid of transitive and unused dependencies.